# Python SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal: Open and close command

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to program and it always gave error. Where's the problem?
I didn't understand how it works. 
I already put the command open and close read .txt

```
 import time
print ("Oi Y")
time.sleep (2)
import time
print ("Sou Crash e fui criado pelo pai CrashX")
time.sleep (2)
import time
print ("O pai me pediu que eu leio para você")
time.sleep (2)
import time
print ("Aguarde")
time.sleep (5)
import time

f = open("C:\P.txt", 'r')
file_data = f.read()
print (file_data)
time.sleep (10)
file_data2 = f.close()
print (file_data2)

import time
print ("Encerrando...")
time.sleep (5)
import time
print ("Obrigado!)
time.sleep (5)
```

Comment: The error means you started a quote (") and never finished it. Look here: `print ("Obrigado!)`

Comment: Thanks!!! I didn't realize hahahaha